# Move to ball like angry bird

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My question is How to move a ball in cocos 2d using Space manager.but when the ball move the screen will also move like angry bird.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

"Learning Cocos2D" by Strougo and Wenderlich is pretty good, although there are some omissions.  For example it doesn't discuss how to save state, although people might be expected to look elsewhere for that because it's standard iOS.  http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Cocos2D-Hands-Building-Addison-Wesley/dp/0321735625

On the other hand, Ray Wenderlich's website is fantastic and discusses a lot of stuff that doesn't make it into his book, including saving state.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Also check out the official Cocos2D programming guide, which is probably how many of us got going.  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index

If you don't actually know Objective-C yet, or any other language, Kochan's book is good: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Objective-Stephen-G-Kochan/dp/0672325861

If you already know something like Java, C++, or C# then O'Reilly's Objective-C Pocket Reference is like a mini-conversion course.  It's pretty old but everything in there is stuff you'll still need.  http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objective-C-Pocket-Reference-Andrew-Duncan/dp/0596004230